# Custom list item permissions and "Access Denied"

Tags: list, permissions, access-denied, inheritance

I have a list where my user ("user1", for example) is creating an item. He can do it because he is in group "My site - members" which has contribute rights on this site.
Then, when the item is created, my administrator breaks inheritance of permissions for the item and deletes everyone's permissions except user1. He also sets permission level for user1 to "read".
Now, my user1 can see the item in list view, but if he will try to access this item (DispForm) he'll get an "Access Denied" error.

I assume I did something wrong with SharePoint permission inheritance or something around it, but I can't understand what should I do to make it work properly.

**UPDATE:**

Found out that the problem only occurs with my custom DispForm, but not with the default one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem!

This can happen if custom Display Form (itself or any of its user controls) has SharePoint controls with "ControlMode" property set to "Edit" instead of "Display". If user have only read (but not contribute) permissions he'll get "Access Denied" message.